# Recursive methods of singly linked list

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

Can anyone review the methods? If there are better ways to write a certain method I would appreciate it if anyone could tell me.

```
public class Node<E> {
    E data;
    Node<E> next;

    public Node(E item) {
        setData(item);
        setNext(null);
    }

    public Node(E item, Node<E> Ref) {
        setData(item);
        setNext(Ref);
    }

    public E getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(E item) {
        data = item;
    }

    public Node<E> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<E> Ref) {
        next = Ref;
    }
}

class MySinglyLinkedList<E> {
    // attributes
    private int size;
    private Node<E> head;

    // methods
    public MySinglyLinkedList() {
        size = 0;
        head = null;
    }

    // Method size
    private int sizeHelper(Node<E> head) { // Helper Method
        if (head == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1 + sizeHelper(head.next);
    }

    public int size() { // Wrapper Method
        return sizeHelper(head);
    }

    // Method add
    private boolean addHelper(Node<E> head, E data) { // Helper Method
        if (head.next == null) {
            head.next = new Node<E>(data);
            return true;
        } else
            return addHelper(head.next, data);
    }

    public boolean add(E data) { // Wrapper Method
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node<E>(data);
            return true;
        } else
            return addHelper(head, data);
    }

    // Method toString
    private String toStringHelper(Node<E> head) { // Helper Method
        if (head == null)
            return "";
        else
            return head.data + "\n" + toStringHelper(head.next);
    }

    public String toString() { // Wrapper Method
        return toStringHelper(head);
    }

    // Method get
    private Node<E> getNodeHelper(int i, Node<E> head) { // Helper Method
        if (i == 0)
            return head;
        else
            return getNodeHelper(i - 1, head.next);
    }

    public Node<E> getNode(int i) { // Wrapper Method
        if (head == null)
            return null;
        else
            return getNodeHelper(i, head);
    }

    // Method indexOf
    private boolean indexOfHelper(E data, Node<E> tmp) { // Helper Method
        if (tmp == null)
            return false;
        else if (tmp.data.equals(data))
            return true;
        tmp = tmp.next;
        return indexOfHelper(data, tmp);
    }

    public boolean indexOf(E data) { // Wrapper Method
        return indexOfHelper(data, head);
    }

    // Method remove
    private boolean removeHelper(Node<E> head, Node<E> pred, E outData) { // Helper Method
        if (head == null)
            return false;
        else if (head.data.equals(outData)) {
            pred.next = head.next;
            return true;
        } else
            return removeHelper(head.next, head, outData);
    }

    public boolean remove(E outData) { // Wrapper Method
        if (head == null)
            return false;
        else if (head.data.equals(outData)) {
            head = head.next;
            return true;
        } else
            return removeHelper(head.next, head, outData);
    }

    // Method insert
    public Node<E> insert(Node<E> head, int i) { // Wrapper Method
        if (head == null)
            head = new Node(i, null);
        else
            head.next = insert(head.next, i);

        return head;
    }

    // Method insertBefore
    private boolean insertBeforeHelper(E e1, E e2, Node<E> head) { // Helper Method
        if (head.next == null)
            return false;
        else if (head.next.data.equals(e1)) {
            Node<E> tmp = new Node<E>(e2);
            tmp.next = head.next;
            head.next = tmp;
            return true;
        } else
            return insertBeforeHelper(e1, e2, head.next);
    }

    public boolean insertBefore(E e1, E e2) { // Wrapper Method
        if (head == null)
            return false;
        else
            return insertBeforeHelper(e1, e2, head);
    }

    // Method reverse
    private Node<E> reverseHelper(Node<E> head, Node<E> prev) { // Helper Method
        if (head == null)
            return head;
        else if (head.next == null) {
            head.next = prev;
            return head;
        } else {
            Node<E> next = head.next;
            head.next = prev;
            return reverseHelper(next, head);
        }
    }

    public Node<E> reverse(Node<E> head) { // Wrapper Method
        return reverseHelper(head, null);
    }

    // Method replace
    private void replaceHelper(Node<E> head, E oldObj, E newObj) { // Helper Method
        if (head != null) {
            if (oldObj.equals(head.data))
                head.data = newObj;
            replaceHelper(head.next, oldObj, newObj);
        }
    }

    public void replace(E oldObj, E newObj) { // Wrapper Method
        replaceHelper(head, oldObj, newObj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code that you have is clear, properly indented *and* easily readable. Internal methods are `private` while the public API is `public`, which is a very good thing.

I have a handful of comments:

- You have a member `private int size;` but it is unused at the moment. You might want to consider removing it - [unused code should be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699995/why-unused-code-should-be-deleted). However, a better alternative would be to use it as a cache for the `size()` method. In the `add()` method, you can increment it by one when an object is added, similarly, in the `remove()` method, you can decrement it by one when an object is removed.
- You should try to [always write the curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020228/is-it-ok-if-i-omit-curly-braces-in-java) surrounding your `if / else` statements, even if it might be unnecessary. It makes the code less error-prone for the future. For example, in the following code

  ```
  if (head == null)
      return 0;
  else
      return 1 + sizeHelper(head.next);
  ```

  you should have

  ```
  if (head == null) {
      return 0;
  } else {
      return 1 + sizeHelper(head.next);
  }
  ```

  or even

  ```
  if (head == null) {
      return 0;
  }
  return 1 + sizeHelper(head.next);
  ```

  which makes the code slightly shorter (although this might be a matter of opinion).
- Your `indexOf` method returns a `boolean`.

  ```
  public boolean indexOf(E data)
  ```

  this might be confusing for the callers, which would be [less surprised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) to have that method return an `int`, like the standard [`List.indexOf(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-). Consider updating that method to make it return the `int` representing the index of the given element, or `-1` if the element isn't found.
- Your `insert(element, i)` element is also surprising: one would expect this method to insert the given element at the index given, like the standard [`List.add(index, element)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-), but your method appends a node having the value `i` instead. Note that you're using a raw type in this method with `new Node(i, null);`, [which you should never do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Answer (score 1):

It is a BAD idea to handle adding with scanning the whole list – a better choice is keeping a pointer to the last item instead, to access it immediately.

And even WORSE idea is doing things like scanning a list with recursion. It is quite common for the list to contain several hundred or thousands of items, but it is quite UNcommon to go several thousands levels into recursion.

Anyway, if you want to... This routine saves the `if()` branch in the `add` method at the cost of re-assigning all `next` references along the list during the return from recursive scan.

```
private Node<E> addHelper(Node<E> head, E data) { // Helper Method
    if (head == null) {
        return new Node<E>(data);
    } else {
        head.next = addHelper(head.next, data);
        return head;
    }
}

public boolean add(E data) { // Wrapper Method
    head = addHelper(head, data);
}
```

Comment: Functional languages tend to rely on recursion so have [tail call optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) a feature implemented for specific cases in the Java Virtual Machine. Not sure if this particular source code is tail recursive or not and if the JVM support would apply or not. See [What limitations does the JVM impose on tail-call optimization](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/157684/what-limitations-does-the-jvm-impose-on-tail-call-optimization).

Answer (score 1):

- Traditional coding conventions call for parameter names to start with lower case.  Some methods have a parameter named `Ref`
- Is there any point to the `boolean` return value of `add` and `addHelper`? It seems like it will always return `true`.
- You seem to avoid `Node` being part of your public interface.  Accordingly, `Node` should not be a public class.  Also, you use `Node` in your public `insert()` method.
- `getNodeHelper` should handle the case where i is greater than the number of nodes.
- `indexOf` should probably be named `firstIndexOf` since there could be multiple matches, but it only finds the first.
- same with `remove`
- not sure what it means to reverse a single `Node`

Comment: My guess for the `add` method is consistency over the standard [`Collection.add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add-E-) which returns `true` when the collection was changed. So I find returning `true` the least surprising result.